# Show text one by one character using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I want to show the text that is in a `ul` tag one by one on mouseover of some text. It is showing some error. How can I fix it?

You can check the code mouseover on "hover here hover again" link in [a link](http://wordpress.vinspro.org/invus/jquery-type.html). Is there another way to do it?

Comment: Interesting - you're looping over the actual HTML one character at a time, so the tags are briefly exposed.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4074399/what-to-choose-for-typewriter-effect-in-javascript

Comment: this is showing simple text . I want to show text that is in inside the ul tag.

Answer (score 0):

You are gettign errors because you are calling a function which is not defined:
`hideCaption`

Comment: @Michael Berkowski already respond to that problem. It comes from the fact you display char per char. So `<` is displayed then `</` and only when `</l`appears the browser interpretes this as a tag.

Comment: One way to fix this would be to append the all tag at once. So when you meet a `<` you print until the next `>`.